# Working with numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem where I have to calculate what records should be included in a query based on a column.

My Table looks something like this

```
Client_Id   Event   ProductID   Date            Cart

1           rem     28          2012-02-23      573473
1           add     28          2012-02-23      573473
1           rem     24          2012-02-23      573473
```

As you can see there is an add and rem in the Event column, this basically means a user has either add or removed the product from their cart.

What I need to get is the records only if the value of say productID 28 is positive.

28 add one, remove = 0 meaningthey don't have the item in their cart.

The query I wrote for this is like:

```
SELECT Client_Id,
       Event,
       ProductID,
       Date,
       Cart
FROM   (SELECT *,
               'Include' = CASE
                             WHEN Total > 0 THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                           END
        FROM   (SELECT *,
                       [ADD] + REM AS Total
                FROM   (SELECT *,
                               'ADD' = CASE
                                         WHEN Event = 'add' THEN 1
                                         ELSE 0
                                       END,
                               'REM' = CASE
                                         WHEN Event = 'rem' THEN -1
                                         ELSE 0
                                       END
                        FROM   Feed) a)b)c
WHERE  c.[Include] = 1
```

But I can't help but to think this is wrong as it's only calculating for the productID in that row not the total rows.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: The order isn't relevant as long as it returns the correct rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps consider using a combination of:

- Convert the 'add' and 'rem' to +1 and -1 respectively with SELECT / UNION ALL
- Aggregate the results using GROUP BY and SUM

Here's a pseudo SQL illustrating the above concepts:

```
select sum(quantity), Client_Id, ProductId, Cart
from
(
select  1 quantity, *
from    feed
where  event = 'add'
union all
select  -1 quantity, *
from    feed
where  event = 'rem'
) temp
Group BY Client_Id, ProductId, Cart
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT sum(CASE WHEN event = 'add'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
           productid
      FROM feed
     GROUP BY productid
     HAVING sum(DECODE(event,'rem', 0, 'add' ,1,0)) > 0
      ) A, feed
  WHERE A.productid = feed.productid
```

Comment: That'll work as long as either quantity is always one, or quantity isn't required. Nice by the way...

Answer (score 0):

Think sideways time
If it's a remove operation multiply productid by -1, then sum and select for > 0.

However what happens if they add two 28s. That would give you 56, which is something else....

Personally I'd ditch the event column and add a quantity column, make that negative for removes. The you could add 5 28s and remove 4 etc...

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to work off the Event column, else I would've used a Quantity column

Comment: So what do you want to see if there are two add 28s, two records or one record with qty of two? Easiest way to get what you want is to generate a quantity column from event so you should have used one. Too late?